# acts_as_tenant gem is creating errors using RSpec/FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, acts-as-tenant

I am attempting to use the `acts_as_tenant` gem to scope SQL queries for multiple organizations. RSpec/FactoryGirl are pulling some dirty tricks, however.

A bit of background: in my app, `User` and `Grant` both belong to an `Organization`. Only admin users can create/delete `Grant`s.

Like the gem's documentation advises, I have inserted `acts_as_tenant :organization` into my `Grant` and `User` models. I have also `set_current_tenant_through_filter` and defined a `before_action :set_organization` in my `application_controller.rb`. Queries for `User` and `Grant` are scoped to the current user's `Organization` only:

```
  def set_organization
    if current_user
      current_organization = Organization.find(current_user.organization_id)
      set_current_tenant(current_organization)      
    end
  end
```

All seems well and good. Now to write controller tests:

```
# grants_controller_spec.rb

describe GrantsController do
  let(:organization) { create(:organization) }
  let(:admin) { create(:user, admin: true, organization_id: organization.id) }
  ...
  before(:each) { log_in admin }
  ...
end
```

The admin part raises an odd error:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:admin) { create(:user, admin: true, organization_id: organization.id) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Organization can't be blank
```

So, even though I have specifically passed the organization's foreign key to FactoryGirl, it's still having issues identifying the `Organization`.

When I comment out the `acts_as_tenant`-specific code, the errors go away. How can I make the tests go green for good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually has very little to do with the code I posted above. The culprit was this line, in my `User` model:

```
attr_accessor :organization_id
```

I believe that line prevented the actual `organization_id` database column from being saved with the model. My `UsersController` code can clarify this:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    organization = Organization.find_by(name: params[:user][:organization_name])
    if organization.authenticated?(params[:user][:organization_password])
      @user.organization_id = organization.id
      @user.save
      ...
end
```

So `organization_id` was indeed set to `organization.id`, but `attr_accessor` was evaluated first, so `organization_id` became a useless virtual attribute. And the db column `organization_id` was saved as `nil`, i.e., nothing was passed to it. This in turn caused `acts_as_tenant` to complain since I'd set the `current_tenant` as the current user's organization, and the current user wasn't getting set up with a foreign key.

My advice to myself and to all others who stumble upon this: check whether your db column names are shadowed by your virtual attributes.